# OpenPyxl - problem with saving file to the specified directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to save my excel files to the directory pointed out by the user.

```
file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()


print(y)
for x in range(2, (int(y))+1):
        newname = "%03d" % x
        wb.save(f''+file_path+filewithoutextension+'- '+newname+'.'+fileextension)
        print (filewithoutextension+'- '+newname+'.'+fileextension)
```

The following code doesn't work properly, as I have the situation in the image below.

[image]

Despite saving the file in the selected directory, the filename inherits the name of the directory folder and is saved in the same folder where the python file is located.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to share the complete code for others to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to generate the file path correctly, you're missing a slash between `file_path` and `filewithoutextension`. I don't have full context for your code, so I can mostly only guess at the exact right implementation, but in general I recommend always using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) when dealing with any kind of path. Give this a shot:

```py
from pathlib import Path

file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()

print(y)
for x in range(2, (int(y)) + 1):
    save_path = Path(file_path) / f"{file_without_extension}-{x:03}.{file_extension}"
    wb.save(save_path)
    print(save_path.name)
```

Also, here's a cleaner way to generate the necessary path from the original file path (requires Python 3.9.x):

```py
new_path = Path(file_path) / original_file_path
save_path = new_path.with_stem(f"{original_file_path.stem}-{x:03}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os` module to create path, also it is better to use f-string to name your file :

```
import os

file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()


print(y)
for x in range(2, (int(y))+1):
    newname = "%03d" % x
    wb.save(os.path.join(file_path,f'filewithoutextension- {newname}.{fileextension}')
```

If the code above gives you an error, you need to make sure that your directory exists at first place.

Comment: Highly recommend against the usage of `os` for dealing with paths. This is the old way of doing things, it's far more verbose, and less powerful than `pathlib`